# Vim editor showing additional two columns

Tags: vim

When I open a file in vim editor, after a few seconds, a additional two columns with random text appears in the window. Can anyone tell me, what it is and how to rectify it?

I am attaching a screen-shot of the problem :

[image]

Comment: did you try to reinstall it?

Comment: You have a plugin installed that is causing this. Please find the plugin and review its documentation or remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sigh…

That column is the "sign column" and you can read about it and the related "signs" feature in `:help signs`.

What you see is the marks present in your file as displayed by a plugin, most likely [ShowMarks](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=152).

If you don't want it, why did you install it?

Comment: Many thanks! Yes they appear to be showmarks. They can be toggled on and off using `\mt`. I have mistakenly pressed the keys during past use.